# CustomAction DriverPackageInstall failing with 0x80030005

Tags: wix

I am having WDF driver installing using WiX installer via custom action
using API DriverPackageInstall. but its failing with error "0x80030005" STG_E_ACCESSDENIED.
I am running as admin (assuming no priviledge issues)
created test "c" console application that is able to install driver successfully.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action='UninstallDriver'
             After='InstallInitialize'>
                    REMOVE~="ALL" OR REINSTALL</Custom>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>      
  <CustomAction Id='UninstallDriver'
                BinaryKey='install_lib'
                DllEntry='InstallDriver'
                Execute='deferred'
                Impersonate="no"
                Return='check'/>
```

Not able to figure why is it failing 
enabled full logs and checked.

```
MSI (s) (E8:50) [11:56:09:296]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\XXXXXX.tmp, Entrypoint: InstallMyDriver
CustomAction InstallMY.XXXXX_9XX_XXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXX returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 11:56:10: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (E8:38) [11:56:10:144]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (E8:38) [11:56:10:144]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (E8:38) [11:56:10:144]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
```

Checked INF file is present at expected input location.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Similar Answer***: [WiX silent install unable to launch built in .EXE: WiX v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832177/wix-silent-install-unable-to-launch-built-in-exe-wix-v3/51845307#51845307)

---

***Driver element***: Why do you not use WiX's built-in **[difx:Driver element / construct](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html)**? I am wondering if you have a system context / impersonation problem? By using the built-in driver element you get more "**auto-magic**" in the sense that you can avoid certain common problems that occur when you do things "manually".

***Blast From The Past***: Here is a previous answer which tersely describes this element. I have unfortunately not been able to test it properly myself: **[How do I use WiX to deploy an INF-based USB driver Plus all the start menu shortcuts and desktop icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989646/how-do-i-use-wix-to-deploy-an-inf-based-usb-driver-plus-all-the-start-menu-short/46005585#46005585)**

***Testing***: I would definitely give this element a try, just comment out your existing custom actions and give it a try.

```
<Component>
   <File ... /> 
   <difx:Driver ... />
</Component>
```

---

- [**Github.com search result showing projects using the difX element**](https://github.com/search?q=difx%3ADriver%20wix%20http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Fwix%2FUtilExtension&type=Code) (and [a direct link to one of them](https://github.com/kobykahane/NpEtw/blob/e4854ee500214d11b435eaba03d5c52cc59396e9/NpEtwSetup/Product.wxs)).
- [Installing driver using cutomAction DriverPackageInstall in wix installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384652/installing-driver-using-cutomaction-driverpackageinstall-in-wix-installer)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, it works fine with difx:Driver construct.

Comment: Great news. Please be sure to test deployment via SCCM or deployment systems if you can (to test for impersonation issues - the installation of your MSI without a logged on context and other strange issues). I also want to alert you to [**how driver installation seems to be changing**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845307/129130). Microsoft seems to want to eliminate driver installation as part of regular setups (or at least put the main driver distribution online via Windows Update). That is all I know basically.

Comment: apologies for incomplete message, I think there are some issues with difx:Driver tag so we are suggested to use DriverPackageInstall.

Comment: I am not able  to figure out what is causing error "0x80030005" STG_E_ACCESSDENIED, even after running as ADMIN

Comment: Is that an OLE2-related error? Hard to say much about it without some sort of log. I have never had success with it, but there is a switch to enable debugging information logging and to flush each log line for `msiexec.exe` (the latter should not be necessary, but maybe try it): `msiexec.exe /i Test.msi /L*vx! Test.log`. What are you doing in this driver? You don't mess with any user-specific files do you?

Comment: As you understand I don't really know much about writing drivers. I was referring to user-context access in HKCU or user profile. I suppose you could do some `procmon.exe` on that console application you wrote that does the test install, just to see what is actually going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181929/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-user3664223).